# Hoverable tag in css materialize doesnt seem to work

Tags: materialize

Hoverable class in `materializecss` doesn't seem to work.Please guide if I need to include any special file or please send the correct syntax.The one i have tried is below:

```
<table class="hoverable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th data-field="id">Name</th>
          <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
          <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/7t5by3nm/ are you actually including the css/js files anywhere?

Comment: No i am not including any files..In the link which you mentioned,hover is working but i again copy pasted the code and ran it in my browser but it is not working...! Is there something that it is compatible with some browsers only??Btw i m using chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Reading your comment @[manan-sheth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251887/manan-sheth), you have to include the files of materializeCSS in your HTMLs, like this, *only the HEAD tag*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   <title>My hoverable table</title>
  </head>
  ...
 </html>
```

Or if you want to download the [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) and save those files in your local, you only need to change the following lines:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

For this lines, *change the path for your path*:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myProject/css/materialice.min.css">
<script src="myProject/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Then the table will be hoverable.